# Angle text using SnapSVG

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Using snapsvg.io, I have say 4 vertical lines of a certain length positioned below a box, evenly spaced out across the x-axis of the box.

What I am not sure how to do is, taking each of these vertical lines and adding a text label to each line that is stacked evenly across each line but at certain heights and displayed at a 45 degree angle, in order to make the text readable, across each vertical line, leftmost to rightmost.

The height of each text label, with the first label positioned at the bottom of the leftmost vertical line with a 45 degree angle and so forth across to the next vertical line, at a different height position, at a 45 degree angle etc.

I have the following but don't believe the syntax is correct.

```
var text = s.text(100, 100, 'Vert-Line-1');

text.attr({
  fill: stroke,
  fontSize: '9px',
  'font-weight': '600',
  'text-anchor': 'start',
  'transform': 'rotate(30 20,40)'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the transform should work. Try a couple of things...

Firstly this looks wrong, as it has a dash/minus sign in there.

```
Vert-Line-1
```

Try

```
VertLine1
```

As a variable name (if thats what its supposed to be) when defining it, and using it.

You could also try the following, and use transform strings if that doesn't work...So instead of

```
'transform': 'rotate(30 20,40)'
```

Try

```
transform: 'r30,20,40'
```

However, the first example should still work, it's technically correct, but including the 2nd just to see if it makes any difference if the first fix didn't work.

Otherwise, do you see any errors in the console ? Is 'stroke' defined,